# Redirect/forward to another action and sending post parameters in symfony

Tags: php, post, symfony1, symfony-1.4, http-post

In my case, I have a small form with login and password, once submitted, the login/pass are used to open an **imap conn to retrieve the user's emails**, once the array of emails retrieved in the same action, I want to **redirect to another action** that **uses this array for other treatements** !

How is that possible? I mean **redirection to another action and sending the whole array as post parameter** ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a `$this->forward()` method `$this->getRequest()->setParameter()` and in the action.

For example:

1. in the first action:

   ```
   $this->getRequest()->setParameter('emails',array('first@email.com','second@email.com','third@email.com'));

   $this->forward('anotherModule','anotherAction');
   ```
2. in the another action:

   ```
   print_r($this->getRequest()->getParameter('emails'));
   ```

Comment: Yeah, this might be the best way. You're not actually redirecting to another page. It's the same URL, only different action executed in Symfony. So you don't actually need to pass the array to another page, but to a different action.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put in session? Either `$user->setAttribute()` or `$user->setFlash()`

Comment: I have been told that puting that in a session is not really a good idea!

Comment: besides, the array that am tring to send is a little big

Comment: Well, depending on your situation it's either 'post' (not such a good idea), session (yes, passing huge amounts of data between pages generally isn't a great decision, but there can be exceptions) or writing the data to a file or database...